# HTML5 elements lose CSS classes when printing in IE8

Tags: css, html, printing, internet-explorer-8, preview

I've got a requirement to support reasonably pretty printing in IE8. I ran into an issue today with a page that's using some HTMl5 functionality (sections) and CSS. The problem only occurs when printing. Looking at the example below, it should generate some underlined text. That works fine. But when printing, it's not underlined. This can be "fixed" by changing the 'section' to a 'div', but for various reasons I'd rather not do that.

Does anyone have any advice? This doesn't appear to be an issue with executing javascript during the print preview, because I can add "window.onload" event to the page to have it populate a div with content, and that works fine in the print preview. And normal CSS works fine in print preview; if I didn't have ".SigLine" nested inside of ".Signature", it would work fine in print preview. But it appears that the "Section" tag's CSS class is getting ignored somehow, thus the nested "SigLine" div doesn't consider itself a child of a "Signature" element.

Here's a complete working example

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
        .Signature .SigLine{border-bottom:solid 1px #000} 
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section class="Signature"> <!-- Make this a <div> and everything's fine... -->
<div class="SigLine" style="width: 400px;">I should be underlined...</div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I noticed the same behavior with Modernizr, which requires a specific print shim script to be added. Not sure if your compatibility script might require the same?

Comment: You're missing the doctype, by the way...

Comment: I spent days trying to find as to why IE8 was not honoring the styles that I set for the print media. I thought since I had already included the html5-shiv and css for mapping the html5 elements to block elements, it will work as expected. No, not IE8. Finally, found this post which lead to modernizr print-support shiv. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'd mark Tim's comment above as the Answer if it would let me, since it sent me off to look for Modernizr's print shim, which led me to http://davidwalsh.name/html5-print, and then https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv-printshiv.js. By including the js file in my example, it resolves my printing issues in IE8. I'm not sure whether there will be any other fallout from using this shiv, but it certainly seems to address my specific concern.

Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 1):

you must include this tag to your HTML code and create a css file called print and,after that you must write the specific css code for the IE8,this is called @media print query

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/print.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

and please note that HTML5shiv do not supports IE8 while you're printing in order to print correctly in IE8 you must include the html5shiv.print in your document too.
you can get it from the [Modernizer website](http://modernizr.com/download/) and you can use this [html5shiv print](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv-printshiv.js) from Github

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the descendant class call. Just call the .SigLine directly.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
    .SigLine{border-bottom:solid 1px #000} 
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I mentioned in my original post that "if I didn't have '.SigLine' nested inside of '.Signature', it would work fine in print preview". In this small example there's obviously no need to nets the CSS classes, but in a real system that would be an unrealistic constraint.